# Static access pattern in Distributed Databases

Tags: distributed-systems, databases

> The access patterns of user requests may be **static**, so that they do
>   not change over time, or dynamic. It is obviously considerably easier to plan for
>   and manage the **static** environments than would be the case for dynamic distributed
>   systems. Unfortunately, it is difficult to find many real-life distributed applications
>   that would be classified as **static**. The significant question, then, is not whether a
>   system is static or dynamic, but how dynamic it is. Incidentally, it is along this
>   dimension that the relationship between the distributed database design and query
>   processing is established.

What does it mean for an access pattern to be “static”? Could you show a practical example of a static access pattern?

Comment: I added a reference please check the link http://www.bwor.net/ebook/Reference.pdf 2nd page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what you copied in the following [text](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-8834-8_3)

The idea is that users access (querying, updating or etc ..) of the database changes with time. It may be at its peaks in sale seasons for example if the database belongs to a commercial applications. etc .. - if it is always fixed and predicted then it is static.

From your copied text: it says that: "it is difficult to find many real-life distributed applications that would be classified as static. The significant question, then, is not whether a system is static or dynamic, but how dynamic it is." --

perhaps, a static access pattern is a collection of sensor nodes that update the database with their readings in a periodic time, with equal size updates always. -- or a set of servers that get a synchronization clock in a periodic manner  (quite theoritical i guess)

Comment: I think there an example of my head to represent Static access pattern I hope this example is correct that is many sql statement not changed and the user run it over same data there no update for this data so that correct ?

Comment: I dont get your question. I am sorry

Comment: I only want to give an example of static access pattern and I ask if this example correct or not to represent static access pattern. So my example is available many SQL Statement that user/users  run on table/tables but sql statement not changed over the time and data on table not updated over the time so this meaning sql statement only read from the tables so this example correct ?

Comment: for my understanding, the refrence did not differentiate between read queries or update queries .. so No, it s not a right example. Except if you know when and how much the user will submit the SELECT queries.

Comment: Perhaps, if you have more questions - ask them in a different post. Also, if the answer is correct then considered as a correct solution.

Comment: Now the static access pattern exatly in SQL statements ?